# How to get the data from specific index in json

Tags: php, json

when i try to get the data from json file ,, it give me all the index in 1 array

i want show the specific index

this is my code

```
<?php
$clawwwx = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/game/by-summoner/43216818/recent?api_key=010ba2bc-2c40-4b98-873e-b1d148c9e379";
$z0rrrx = file_get_contents($clawwwx);
$gazaaax = json_decode($z0rrrx, true);



foreach ($gazaaax['games'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['gameType'] == 'MATCHED_GAME') {
    echo $value['stats']['totalDamageDealtToChampions'];
    }
}
```

i want this         `echo $value['stats']['totalDamageDealtToChampions'];`

to echo the index what i want ,, not all the data from all index

Comment: `$key` is your index

Comment: so... `if (!in_array($key, array(ids, that, you, awnt)) { continue; }`

Comment: It would be nice to see the data going into the foreach

Comment: you can see the data here https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/game/by-summoner/43216818/recent?api_key=010ba2bc-2c40-4b98-873e-b1d148c9e379

Answer (score 0):

Just simply `echo $key;` :) You assign it to $key in foreach()

Comment: i try this it give me the array with index 0123456789 if i want to show the data from index 0 how ?!

Comment: I'm not sure, what you exactly want... the $key does not return an array.

Comment: do $var[0] where 0 is the index and $var is the array

Comment: try the code in localhost it will give u the data for totalDamageDealtToChampions in all index ! , what i want is just for the index i chose